# Enqueued event for Queue<T> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, .net-4.0

I am new to event and delegates. How can I implement an enqueued event for an object of type `Queue<T>`?

I am using C# and .Net 4.0

Comment: Since `Queue<T>` does not already have such an event, and all the manipulation methods (i.e. Enqueue, Dequeue, etc.) are non-virtual, you simply cannot safely provide this functionality on that class.  Your better off writing your own Queue class that implement these events, and perhaps using the native `Queue<T>` as a backing store.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can encapsulate the Queue class with your own class, something like:

```
class MyQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();     
    public event EventHandler Enqueued;     
    protected virtual void OnEnqueued()     
    {         
        if (Enqueued != null) 
        Enqueued(this, EventArgs e);     
    }     
    public virtual void Enqueue(T item)     
    {         
        queue.Enqueue(item);         
        OnEnqueued();     
    }     
    public int Count 
     {
             get 
             { 
                     return queue.Count; 
             }
     }
    public virtual T Dequeue()     
    {
            T item = queue.Dequeue();         
            OnEnqueued();
            return item;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are no events fired from the System.Collections.* suite of classes. Since you're using .NET 4.0, you may want to look into [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) instead which, instead of relying on events, you would use [the Producer-Consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) to Take elements from the collection as they arrive from another thread. [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) will take care of all thread-safety and synchronization for you efficiently.

The default backing type for [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) is [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0) which sounds like what you want, but it should be noted that you can change it to use a [`ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=net-5.0) or [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-5.0) if you want/don't mind different ordering characteristics.

Another great feature of [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) is the ability to [set bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-bounding-and-blocking) which can help block the producer from adding more items to the collection than the consumers can keep up with.

For a great write up on all aspects of this subject, I suggest checking out [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem) from Alexeandra Rusina. The post also covers ways to work with BlockingCollection using the [Task Parallel Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-parallel-library).

Comment: it's the rare soul who wants to use a queue that doesn't care about ordering characteristics. ;)

Comment: Yes of course it would seem the original question was most interested in a queue, but I just wanted to point out that BlockingCollection can use many diff. backing stores.

Comment: Never heard of BlockingCollection!! Looking it up right now. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 BlockingCollection never crossed my path... exchanging my implementation right now! Thanks!

Comment: I am +1 due to that article; very well written and a great demonstration that does not use `while(true)`