# How to listen to a variable value change from different threads?

Tags: c#

I have a static Queue collection. I have a thread that en-queue to it. I have multiple waiting threads which needs to listen to any en-queue event on the Queue collection and do a task. How to achieve this in C#?

The thread which is inserting should never be blocked. But all the threads that are listening to should instantly get notified and do some other work using the data and then listen again as soon as the job is over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: Enqueued event for Queue<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836311/c-enqueued-event-for-queuet)

Comment: Choose whatever you like [Overview of Synchronization Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

Comment: Consider using a concurrent collection such as [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

Comment: Okay thank you. I was just making sure that the link you sent address my question precisely.

Comment: Seems like it would simplify things to have the queue on the main thread and use async named pipes to communicated the event data from each thread.

Comment: That would work, thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually BlockingCollection was exactly what I needed. I initially thought it would block the whole listening thread, however the listening thread fires events as I wanted while it is still waiting for consuming from the producer.